Vuetify 3, using a combobox in a v-for sends warning
I'm using Vuetify 3.5.14. I have a v-for for levels. On each level i have few spells represented by a combobox
When i select the value of a combobox, it works fine, but when i try to search inside the combobox a value and then select that value, it triggers a warning:

I assume that's because i have a lot of items in the array (286 items, and i checked all the ids, they're unique), but it triggers sometimes even with 10 items.
This is a link to reproduce it via vuetify 3 playground
Vuetify 3 Playground
I know it's just a warning and i could ignore it, but i prefer to resolve it.
Any suggestion?
EDIT:
here's the full error
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:50 [Vue warn]: Vuetify error: Multiple nodes with the same ID
    288
    288 
  at <VListItem title="Birthright" value=288 ref=fn<fn>  ... > 
  at <VVirtualScrollItem key=1 renderless=true onUpdate:height=fn<onUpdate:height> > 
  at <VVirtualScroll ref=Ref< Proxy(Object) {…} > renderless=true items= (34) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] > 
  at <VListChildren items= [] returnObject=false > 
  at <VList ref=Ref< Proxy(Object) {…} > selected= [274] selectStrategy="independent"  ... > 
  at <VDefaultsProvider root="VMenu" > 
  at <BaseTransition onAfterEnter=fn<onAfterEnter> onAfterLeave=fn<onAfterLeave> appear=true  ... > 
  at <Transition appear=true persisted=true target= <div class=​"v-field v-field--active v-field--appended v-field--center-affix v-field--dirty v-field--variant-outlined v-theme--fall v-locale--is-ltr" role=​"combobox">​…​</div>​  ... > 
  at <MaybeTransition appear=true persisted=true transition=false  ... > 
  at <VOverlay ref=Ref< Proxy(Object) {…} > id="v-menu-253" class="v-menu"  ... > 
  at <VMenu ref=Ref< Proxy(Object) {…} > modelValue=true onUpdate:modelValue=fn<onUpdate:modelValue>  ... > 
  at <VField ref=Ref< Proxy(Object) {…} > onMousedown=fn<onControlMousedown> onClick=fn<onControlClick>  ... > 
  at <VInput ref=Ref< Proxy(Object) {…} > modelValue="" onUpdate:modelValue=fn<onUpdate:modelValue>  ... > 
  at <VTextField ref=Ref< Proxy(Object) {…} > autofocus=false counter=false  ... > 
  at <VCombobox clearable="" chips="" multiple=""  ... > 
  at <VCol cols="6" sm="6" class="mt-n2" > 
  at <VRow> 
  at <VContainer> 
  at <VSheet class="mx-auto mt-6" height="100%" width="85%" > 
  at <MyEquipment build_id=2 > 
  at <BaseTransition appear=false persisted=false mode=undefined  ... > 
  at <Transition name="v-window-x-reverse-transition" onBeforeEnter=fn<onBeforeTransition> onAfterEnter=fn<onAfterTransition>  ... > 
  at <MaybeTransition transition= {name: 'v-window-x-reverse-transition', onBeforeEnter: ƒ, onAfterEnter: ƒ, onEnterCancelled: ƒ, onBeforeLeave: ƒ, …} disabled=false > 
  at <VWindowItem value="build_equipment" > 
  at <VWindow modelValue="build_equipment" onUpdate:modelValue=fn > 
  at <VCardText> 
  at <VCard key=0 elevation=24 > 
  at <[id] onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< Proxy(Object) {__v_skip: true} > > 
  at <Anonymous key="/builds/2()" vnode= {__v_isVNode: true, __v_skip: true, type: {…}, props: {…}, key: null, …} route= {fullPath: '/builds/2', path: '/builds/2', query: {…}, hash: '', name: 'builds-id', …}  ... > 
  at <RouterView name=undefined route=undefined > 
  at <NuxtPage> 
  at <Builds onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< Proxy(Object) {…} > > 
  at <Anonymous key="/builds" vnode= {__v_isVNode: true, __v_skip: true, type: {…}, props: {…}, key: null, …} route= {fullPath: '/builds/2', path: '/builds/2', query: {…}, hash: '', name: 'builds-id', …}  ... > 
  at <RouterView name=undefined route=undefined > 
  at <NuxtPage> 
  at <VContainer> 
  at <VMain> 
  at <VLayout> 
  at <Default ref=Ref< Proxy(Object) {…} > > 
  at <LayoutLoader key="default" layoutProps= {ref: RefImpl} name="default" > 
  at <NuxtLayoutProvider layoutProps= {ref: RefImpl} key="default" name="default"  ... > 
  at <NuxtLayout> 
  at <ClientOnly> 
  at <App key=4 > 
  at <NuxtRoot>
warn$1 @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:50
consoleError @ console.mjs?v=d7e5e0ef:9
register @ nested.mjs?v=d7e5e0ef:124
useNestedItem @ nested.mjs?v=d7e5e0ef:240
setup @ VListItem.mjs?v=d7e5e0ef:99
setup @ defineComponent.mjs?v=d7e5e0ef:33
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:197
setupStatefulComponent @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:7886
setupComponent @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:7847
mountComponent @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:5203
processComponent @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:5169
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:4685
mountChildren @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:4917
processFragment @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:5099
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:4659
mountChildren @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:4917
processFragment @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:5099
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:4659
componentUpdateFn @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:5313
run @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:195
setupRenderEffect @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:5441
mountComponent @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:5216
processComponent @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:5169
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:4685
patchKeyedChildren @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:5626
patchChildren @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:5498
processFragment @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:5143
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:4659
patchKeyedChildren @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:5584
patchChildren @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:5498
processFragment @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:5143
patch @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:4659
componentUpdateFn @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:5393
run @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:195
runIfDirty @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:233
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:197
flushJobs @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:405
Promise.then
queueFlush @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:319
queueJob @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:314
effect2.scheduler @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:5435
trigger @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:223
endBatch @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:281
notify @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:554
trigger @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:528
set value @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:1399
_calculateVisibleItems @ virtual.mjs?v=d7e5e0ef:171
requestAnimationFrame
calculateVisibleItems @ virtual.mjs?v=d7e5e0ef:152
(anonymous) @ virtual.mjs?v=d7e5e0ef:116
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:197
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:204
baseWatchOptions.call @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:6178
job @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:1734
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:197
flushJobs @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:405
Promise.then
queueFlush @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:319
queueJob @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:314
baseWatchOptions.scheduler @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:6190
effect2.scheduler @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:1751
trigger @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:223
endBatch @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:281
notify @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:554
trigger @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:528
set value @ reactivity.esm-bundler.js?v=d7e5e0ef:1399
(anonymous) @ resizeObserver.mjs?v=d7e5e0ef:14


Please, add the error as text, it's relevant. Note that it says about node ids, not ids in your code (they appear as "values" and "keys" to vuetify). Possibly related to https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/20516

@EstusFlask its a big message, i cannot copy and paste it completely

I mean that at least mentioning "Multiple nodes with the same ID"  in the question makes sense. I had to type it manually to search it. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

@EstusFlask thanks, that last link was pretty useful, i edited

The error does not appear if you downgrade to Vuetify 3.7.1.  It looks like the Vuetify developers are actively working on a fix for a future version.

@yoduh im using vuetify 3.5.14...i may need to upgrade to 3.7.1, then

It wouldn't hurt. I missed the fact you included your Vuetify version in your question.  You can change the Vuetify version in the playground in the top right of the page.  The issue is most easily reproducible with the latest version (3.7.3), but I can't reproduce with any version I try <= 3.7.1, including 3.5.14... Weird.

@yoduh Changing the version to 3.7.1 resolved the issue
